# Redirect a pipe chain

Tags: bash, shell

Let's suppose the output of a chain of pipes `command1 | command2` is the name of a file and you want to redirect `<` this file to another command.

I'd like to use something like `command3 < command1 | command2` but it seems that `<` operator has preference over `|`

How to do that without the using of subshells nor subtitutions, just using pipes and redirections?

Example (*):

I'd like to search for the "hello" word in the most recent file doing something like:

```sh
grep "hello" < ls -t | head -n1
```

These solutions from SO users are not valid for me:

```sh
grep "hello" $(ls -t | head -n1)      # command subtitution
ls -t | head -n1 | xargs grep "hello" # no redirection
```

--

(*) This is just an example, I know I don't need redirection for `grep`.
I'm not asking for a particular solution of this example.

Comment: If you can use `zsh` instead of `bash`: `files=( *(om) ); grep -F hello "${files[0]}"` No subshells, pipes *or* redirection needed.

Comment: Are you looking for `xargs`, perhaps?

Comment: @oguzismail `xargs`, subshells and substitutions will work for this specific example. But that's not the point: I want to use redirection after chaining pipes for any command

Comment: You'll need to clarify it a bit more then. I have no idea what you mean by *use redirection after chaining pipes*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xargs cat` :

```
command1 | command2 | command3 | xargs cat | command4
```

`xargs` will execute the command passed as argument for each line of its standard input. Its standard input here is fed by your pipeline producing a filename, so `xargs cat` will output the content of that file, which is then piped to `command4`.

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/Z2PBYb).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> command4 < command1 | command2 | comamnd3
> ```

Why don't move your command to the end of pipechain, as it should be logical? :

```
command1 | command2 | command3 | command4
```

| is not just a redirection, it is pipe with redirection between two separate processes, when < and > are redirection of stdout/stdin belong to the same process, that is why they executes before '|' pipe.

If you want to put your command4 in the beginning by any personal reasons, you can use ( ) to join other commands and then redirect the result using "<<<" redirection, like that:

```
command4 <<< ( command1 | command2 | command3 )
```

And your example:

```
grep "hello" < ls -t | head -n1 (*)
```

For such things you can use xargs:

```
ls -t | head -n1 | xargs grep "hello"
```

Comment: `command4 < ( command1 | command2 | command3 )` is a syntax error. OP don't want to use `command1 | command2 | command3 | command4` because he needs `command4` to have as input the content of the file pointed to by the output of the rest of the pipeline, not the output itself

Comment: Oh, sorry need "<<<" redirection to send string itself instead of "<" - redirect from file..
Updated my answer.
Also, please check version with xargs.

Comment: `xargs` is great for OP's `grep` example and definitely what he should use in this case. But if differs from the general case mentionned in the rest of the question as it takes its parameters as command line arguments rather than standard input